# Failing to verify existing password hashes with ruby BCrypt

Tags: ruby, hash, bcrypt

I'm currently running into an issue trying to implement an authentication on Ruby on Rails against an existing database with existing password hashes. I do have a couple of existing plaintext passwords readily available, so I know a few plaintext/hash pairs to verify the process.

Passwords are stored as `$2a$12$xxxxyyyy`, so I would assume that they are hashed using the BCrypt algorithm (can I really safely assume that?). When I now try to run

```
password = ::BCrypt::Password.new("$2a$12$xxxxyyyy")
verify = password == "known_plaintext_password"
```

I always end up getting `false` for the verification. When I try to manually generate a hash using the same salt with the original password using

```
bcrypt = ::BCrypt::Password.new("$2a$12$xxxxyyyy")
::BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret("known_plaintext_password", bcrypt.salt)
```

the result actually differs from the original hash, though I would expect the hash function to return the same hash when called with the same input password and salt (again, can I safely make this assumption?).

I do not know which platform was used to implement the original hashing process, but I strongly suspect it to be implemented in .NET.

Am I doing something wrong here when trying to verify the password? I personaly would expect a pepper to be used on the original password before generating the hash, can I safely take this assumption, or might there be anything else going on? Are there possible incompatibilities between different implementations of the BCrypt algorith?

Comment: Why not use `BCrypt::Password.create(...)`? Having to compose it with the exposed engine is a strange thing to do.

Comment: Can you validate `"$2a$12$/hLLnmlMGjeUKIR8vNFC2.R/luY9c8vdUoo5720wb0nJkaIWp8Gpe"`? It's the result of `BCrypt::Password.create('test')`.

Comment: Where did this hash come from? If that's the `$2a$` from the [modular crypt format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) then it should work. If whatever generated this mis-tagged it, then all bets are off. Some libraries are buggy and emit `$2a$` even if using a different method but ignore that when decoding, so you may have to substitute that for the correct form, like what happened with old (pre 2011) PHP having to use `$2x$`.

Comment: I used the engine so that I was able to manually add the (known) salt of the original password, so I could compare my generated password with the same salt to the original.
I am able to validate your example password

Comment: You'll need to see what library generated this hash originally and check the documentation for it. I'd guess it's non-standard.

Comment: As I said, I do not know (yet) where the hash was originally generated, query is ongoing... Because of the format I expected it to be BCrypt, but yes, if that's just a mistagging I'll probably be out of luck. Already did try to modify it to `$2b$`, `$2x$` and `$2y$`, without success

Comment: A longshot is throwing some known simple examples at [Hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) which usually explains what method it found.

Comment: I have to assume you have no access to the original code base that generated these? I have seen a lot of old .Net with custom implementations (an amalgamation of known algorithms and custom iterations/manipulations)  of hashing algorithms for "security purposes" and there would be very little chance of recreating the implementation if this source was lost to the ages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there has been no real answer here, and I figured out the solution in the meantime I will add my own answer for reference if anyone else encounters the same problem...

It was indeed the case that the passwords were hashed using a pepper (or secret salt, if you prefer that terminology). Fortunately I was able to get the secret used, and after adding it as a parameter in the devise model authentication against the legacy data was working.